# How to add taggs JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add tags that should be generated by JS. Unfortunately, it's still not working. I see using console.log that links have generated but are not showing on the page.

```
<section class="posts">
                <article class="post active" id="article-1" data-tags="cat cactus scissors">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Article 1</h3>
                    <p class="post-author">by Marion Berry</p>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <p>Duis non dolor efficitur erat interdum fringilla a lobortis dolor. Aenean in massa
                            viverra, pretium augue et, imperdiet diam. Proin varius vitae lectus ut suscipit. Etiam
                            metus lacus, molestie at ante eget, gravida tristique metus. Morbi finibus elit mi, ut
                            aliquam libero tempor eu.</p>
                        <p>Curabitur a arcu ut nunc ornare tempor. Vestibulum et augue purus. Sed mattis auctor
                            iaculis. Duis placerat tempus nisl, et commodo sem varius sed. Ut ac ultrices leo.
                            Aliquam efficitur augue a scelerisque lacinia. Donec sit amet justo lacus.</p>
                        <p> Duis tincidunt tellus non lorem molestie lobortis. Ut nec mauris consectetur, convallis
                            nisl vel, venenatis magna.Sed efficitur egestas purus, eu fermentum leo sodales in.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-tags">
                        <p><strong>Tags:</strong></p>
                        <ul class="list list-horizontal">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </article>
```

Plan of function generateTags:
find all articles

START LOOP: for every article

find tags wrapper

```
make html variable with empty string 

get tags from data-tags attribute

split tags into array

START LOOP: for each tag

  generate HTML of the link

  add generated code to html variable

END LOOP: for each tag

 insert HTML of all the links into the tags wrapper
```

END LOOP: for every article

Below is the javasript code:

````js
function generateTags(){
  const optArticleTagsSelector='.post-tags .list';
  const optArticleSelector = '.post';
  
  
  const articles = document.querySelectorAll(optArticleSelector);
  
  
  for (let article of articles) {
  
 const TagsWrapper = article.querySelectorAll(optArticleTagsSelector);
 TagsWrapper.innerHTML='';
  
let html = '';
  
const articleTags = article.getAttribute('data-tags');

  
  const articleTagsArray = articleTags.split(' ');
  
  
for (let tag of articleTagsArray){
  
  
const HTMLlink = '<li><a href="#tag-' + tag + '"><span>'+ tag +'</span></a></li>';


  
html=html + HTMLlink;


  
  }
  /* insert HTML of all the links into the tags wrapper */
TagsWrapper.innerHTML=html;
console.log(TagsWrapper);
  
}```
````

Comment: Could you paste your code as text?

Comment: Hi CoryCoolguy,
I just added JS code :)